Python linters do not highlight undefined classes in imports
If I try to import any class that does not exist in python, Ruff linter does not highlight it
from numpy import ClassThatDoesNotExist
instance = ClassThatDoesNotExist()

(if I remove the import, Ruff will tell me that the class is not defined.)
I know that it's possible to modify Ruff rules but I cant find one that match this import problem.
I'm also using sonarLint but it does not highlight this error as well.
It's hard for me to believe that this rule is not supported by Ruff.
Does someone know the name of the rule or another linter that could find this error ?
(except pylint, I find it way too slow)

Import resolution depends on configuration and unresolved import errors are sometimes false positive. In addition, package may be written in C with python wrapper, making it impossible for linter to distinguish between correct and incorrect imports. That's why most of the linters do not perform these checks, because it doesn't worth it to implement those.

Thanks for the explanation, Though vscode performs can these checks. When I do (cntrl + hover) on the imported variable, vscode can underline it if it finds it. So maybe there is a way to underline it in red if vscode does not find an import.

I realised that if you want to check for these errors, you might want to use pylance.
pylance comes with the Python extension for Visual Studio Code, but sometimes it's disabled so you might have to enable it.
Then go to:

Python › Analysis: Type Checking Mode, and set it to basic.

This will check all your types and your imports. You can disable and enable different rules, look up to the extension.
If you also want to have type hints, add these options in settings.json :
{     
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true,
}

